# iOS best practice to display errors for a uitableview after pull to refresh and/or scroll to load more

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've recently developed an android app and used toasts to display any errors (network or web service errors) that may have happened when pulling to refresh or scrolling to load more in a table. They were great at displaying these errors without being to invasive or requiring user input to remove.

Seeing as iOS doesn't have a toast equivalent I wanted to know what are considered best practices on iOS to display errors when pulling to refresh or scrolling to load more in a UITableView.

Personally a UIAlertView seems a bit to invasive and requires a user input to remove, but I could be wrong and that may be the standard on iOS. I'm not opposed to using libraries out there that have implemented toast like views, but I figured I'd check if there was a better way since it's not built in.

Any suggestions on this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can add and remove a headerView containing a label that show your error message programatically.

to show:

```
UIView *myView = ...
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myView;
```

to hide:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
```

Comment: And I would add a footer for errors from the scroll to load? That seems like it would work.

Comment: for a footer you can add: self.tableView.tableFooterView =